# Deriving the change in photon frequency under a change of coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to derive the following equation relating the frequency of a photon in a frame $\tilde{O}$ to a frame $O$ with a background perturbation. To be more specific, this is equation 9.10 from Physical Foundations of Cosmology, Mukhanov. The observers $\tilde{O}$ and $O$ are both at rest in their respective coordinate systems which are related by $\tilde{x}^\mu = x^\mu + \xi^\mu$. $p^{\alpha}$ being the 4-momentum of the photon and $\omega = u_\alpha p^\alpha$ where $u^\alpha$ is the 4-velocity of the observer.

In these two coordinate systems, the frequency of the incoming photon is measured to be

\begin{equation}
\overline{\omega} = \omega \bigg(1+ \frac{\partial \xi^i}{\partial \eta}l^i\bigg)
\end{equation}

Where $l^i = -p^i/\vec{p}^2$. Since both $\tilde{O}$ and $O$ are at rest, therefore, using the normalization of their 4-velocity $u^\alpha u_\alpha = 1$ we obtain
\begin{align}
\omega = \frac{p^0}{g_{00}} && \tilde{\omega} = \frac{\tilde{p}^0}{\tilde{g}_{00}}
\end{align}

Mukhanov then says that using the above two relations and the fact that $p^\alpha p_\alpha = 0$ we get the required relation between the frequencies (upto first order in metric and coordinate perturbations). But I am unable to derive the same. The furthest that I have gone is to obtain the following

\begin{equation}
(\tilde{p}^0)^2 = (p^0)^2 + 2\partial_\alpha\xi^i p^\alpha p^i
\end{equation}

But I am unable to derive the said equation. Some help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.